# error: cannot find symbol method setAdListener(<anonymous InterstitialAdListener>) & (<anonymous InterstitialAdListener>)

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-javascript-sdk

error: cannot find symbol method setAdListener()
error: cannot find symbol method setAdListener()

com.facebook.ads.AdView adView_banner = new com.facebook.ads.AdView(this, getString(R.string.facebook_banner_id), AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);

```
    // Find the Ad Container
    LinearLayout adContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adView);

    // Add the ad view to your activity layout
    adContainer.addView(adView_banner);

    adView_banner.setAdListener(new com.facebook.ads.AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
            Log.i("ERR",""+adError.getErrorMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Please add a little background on what you're trying to do and where/when does this error occur. Optionally, providing details on with what technologies and what versions, you get this error, might help in identifying the issue.

Comment: Facebook has updated their code, kindly check their official website for the same

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has updated their current SDK, for your case change your code to
reference
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/guides/ad-formats/banner/android

```
AdListener adListener = new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
                // Ad error callback
                Toast.makeText(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        "Error: " + adError.getErrorMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
                // Ad loaded callback
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
                // Ad clicked callback
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
                // Ad impression logged callback
            }
        };

        // Request an ad
        adView.loadAd(adView.buildLoadAdConfig().withAdListener(adListener).build());
```